# NoSuchMethodError: No static method createViewModelLazy

Tags: android, dependency-injection, viewmodel, dagger, dagger-hilt

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method createViewModelLazy

I'm using hiltViewmodels. However, this error only appears when attempting to instantiate my viewModel in the library module compiled code. I'm using this compiled code in the form of an aar file that is depended on by a different app module.

The Hilt viewModel dependency injection works great in my original project. 
(    val viewModel: FeedViewModel by viewModels()   )

Comment: how did you solved it?

Comment: I ended up with a retro solution: creating viewmodel factories. However, I have since switched to Koin for dependency (and viewModel) injection. Koin seems to keep things simpler in multi module projects, and I no longer have viewModel factories.

In my scenario, a select few of those modules are ultimately shipped to be used in other applications. Koin has the ability to isolate the its DI capability to specific modules or groups of modules. @leodev

Answer (score 4):

I had the same Exception, and managed to fix it in Android Studio.

Just clean the project: Open the "Build" menu and click on "Clean Project".

Now running the app should work again.